# Can't add inline frame to my website's code

Tags: html, iframe

So I have a chatting website with some friends and I'm trying to add a radio player widget to login page. But when I try adding the code and click save button, "iframe" and "document" gets removed automatically. I'm totally new to coding and stuff so I have no idea how to add a radio player widget without using inline frame. Here's the code I'm using. Please pardon my noobiness hehe.

```
<div class="radyoTelekomFooterDIV">
    <div radyotelekom="radyoplayer-v6">
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//radyoplayer.net/players/v6/player.js?v=0.6.0.0"
            charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="path-to-audio-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

- Above is an example of HTML5 audio player code, check if this help you.
- Replace "path-to-audio-file.mp3" with the URL or path to the audio file you want to play.
- HTML5 audio player does not require an iframe.

Comment: Can I change the color and add text to this or is it default?

Comment: You can change the default text 'Your browser does not support the audio element' as well as you can customize audio element using CSS and JavaScript